# adding a value in a new column based on conditions

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I have a dataframe df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['1', '1', '2', '3', '3', '8','4', '1', '2', '4'],
    'start': ['2017-01-02', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01', '2017-04-01', '2017-01-01', '2017-04-01', '2017-05-01', '2017-02-01']
})

df.sort_values(['id', 'start'])
```

I wanted to see if for every id, there existss a second line. if it exist, i wanted to add a new column (lets say num_count) where I want to add integer 1. If there exists only one row per id or the last row of the id, I want to add 0. 
Here is what I want as output.

```
  id num_count       start
0  1         1  2017-01-02
1  1         1  2017-02-01
7  1         0  2017-04-01
2  2         1  2017-03-01
8  2         0  2017-05-01
3  3         1  2017-02-01
4  3         0  2017-03-01
6  4         1  2017-01-01
9  4         0  2017-02-01
5  8         0  2017-04-01
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to assign the result of `.sort_values(..)` given you want to process the *sorted* dataframe:

```
df = df.sort_values(['id', 'start'])
```

You can make use of the [**`duplicated(..)`** function [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) here where, based on your sample output, you want the *last* item of the duplicated data to be `False`.

So we can assign a column like:

```
df['num_count'] = df['id'].duplicated('last').astype(int)
```

This then yields for the sample input:

```
>>> df
  id       start
0  1  2017-01-02
1  1  2017-02-01
7  1  2017-04-01
2  2  2017-03-01
8  2  2017-05-01
3  3  2017-02-01
4  3  2017-03-01
6  4  2017-01-01
9  4  2017-02-01
5  8  2017-04-01
>>> df['num_count'] = df['id'].duplicated('last').astype(int)
>>> df
  id       start  num_count
0  1  2017-01-02          1
1  1  2017-02-01          1
7  1  2017-04-01          0
2  2  2017-03-01          1
8  2  2017-05-01          0
3  3  2017-02-01          1
4  3  2017-03-01          0
6  4  2017-01-01          1
9  4  2017-02-01          0
5  8  2017-04-01          0
```

Comment: Great thank you. I was trying to achieve this using .shift() function but it was getting a bit difficult. Didn't use this duplicated function before. So thank you.